# laravel: grabbing query param value in controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I have am adding the query param `?order=921` to my request and when I check `log_info($request)`, I see this:

```
Pragma:          no-cache
Referer:         https://local/admin/inquire?order=219
Sec-Fetch-Mode:  cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:  same-origin
```

I know `$request->getQueryString()` will grab me `order=219` but is there anyway to just grab the value of order without having to get `$request->getQueryString()` and parsing that?

I have tried to log `log_info($request->order)` but nothing shows up for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$request->order` to do that.

Comment: that was the first thing I tried.  When I try `log_info($request->order)` , nothing shows up

Comment: what is this log_info function? did you implement it yourself?